# How to tackle class imbalance problem in my dataset in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

Hello I am using the ISIC-2019 dataset from kaggle, which has a class imbalance problem. In total there are 25.331 images and I split my data into 80% train, 10% validation and 10% test set.

The class distribution consists of the following:

> Original class distribution: Counter({5: 10338, 4: 3644, 1: 2668, 2:
> 2114, 0: 690, 6: 494, 7: 207, 3: 177})

I am trying to apply the MaxViT_T model from pytorch and have used 2 approaches. I first tried weightedrandomsampling with the following code:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, WeightedRandomSampler
# give weights to the classe
targets = train_dataset.targets
class_count = np.unique(targets, return_counts=True)[1]
print(class_count)

weight = 1. / class_count
samples_weight = weight[targets]
samples_weight = torch.from_numpy(samples_weight)
sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(samples_weight, len(samples_weight))
```

And have tried another approach in which I oversampled the minority class within my dataset:

```
!pip install imblearn
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# Print original class distribution
print("Original class distribution:")
print(Counter(train_dataset.targets))

# Get the targets for each image in the training set
train_targets = [t for _, t in train_dataset]

# Create oversampled minority class
oversampler = RandomOverSampler()
X_resampled, y_resampled = oversampler.fit_resample(train_dataset, train_targets)

# Print new class distribution
print("\nNew class distribution after oversampling:")
print(Counter(y_resampled))


# Create a new dataset with the oversampled minority class
oversampled_train_dataset = datasets.DatasetFolder(root=train_dir, transform=auto_transforms, 
                                                   loader=train_dataset.loader, 
                                                   extensions=train_dataset.extensions,
                                                   target_transform=train_dataset.target_transform)
oversampled_train_dataset.imgs = X_resampled
oversampled_train_dataset.targets = y_resampled

# Create new dataloader with oversampled dataset
train_dataloader = DataLoader(oversampled_train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

Both approaches didn't work and gave me a low accuracy, I applied the last code and after 5 epochs it gave me this result.

```
Epoch 1/20: 100%|██████████| 636/636 [11:51<00:00,  1.12s/batch, acc=0.509, loss=0.045]
Epoch 1/20: 100%|██████████| 79/79 [01:25<00:00,  1.08s/batch, acc=0.5, loss=0.0453]
Epoch: 1    Training Loss: 1.441227     Training Accuracy: 0.509254     Validation Loss: 1.448716   Validation Accuracy: 0.500000
Validation loss decreased (inf --> 1.448716).  Saving model ...
Time per epoch: 797.990 seconds
Epoch 2/20: 100%|██████████| 636/636 [11:38<00:00,  1.10s/batch, acc=0.509, loss=0.0448]
Epoch 2/20: 100%|██████████| 79/79 [01:25<00:00,  1.08s/batch, acc=0.497, loss=0.0456]
Epoch: 2    Training Loss: 1.435197     Training Accuracy: 0.509172     Validation Loss: 1.458443   Validation Accuracy: 0.497231
Time per epoch: 783.683 seconds
Epoch 3/20: 100%|██████████| 636/636 [11:39<00:00,  1.10s/batch, acc=0.509, loss=0.0449]
Epoch 3/20: 100%|██████████| 79/79 [01:24<00:00,  1.07s/batch, acc=0.498, loss=0.0458]
Epoch: 3    Training Loss: 1.436685     Training Accuracy: 0.509139     Validation Loss: 1.466263   Validation Accuracy: 0.498022
Time per epoch: 783.888 seconds
Epoch 4/20: 100%|██████████| 636/636 [11:45<00:00,  1.11s/batch, acc=0.509, loss=0.0449]
Epoch 4/20: 100%|██████████| 79/79 [01:25<00:00,  1.08s/batch, acc=0.498, loss=0.0456]
Epoch: 4    Training Loss: 1.436596     Training Accuracy: 0.509254     Validation Loss: 1.459666   Validation Accuracy: 0.498022
Time per epoch: 790.498 seconds
Epoch 5/20: 100%|██████████| 636/636 [11:41<00:00,  1.10s/batch, acc=0.509, loss=0.0449]
Epoch 5/20: 100%|██████████| 79/79 [01:25<00:00,  1.08s/batch, acc=0.498, loss=0.0457]
Epoch: 5    Training Loss: 1.436793     Training Accuracy: 0.509221     Validation Loss: 1.461350   Validation Accuracy: 0.497627
Time per epoch: 787.196 seconds
```

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong and what other ways I can use when trying to combat the class imbalance problem in my dataset and simultaneously achieve a higher accuracy score.